# How to get an Google Translation API key to connect to Trados Studio?

Tags: google-translation-api

How can I get an Google Translation API key to connect Trados Studio to Google Translation API?

In this instruction of SDL below, the key seems to have been available in the list in "APIs & services > Credentials" of Google Cloud console.

https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__gateway.sdl.com_apex_communityknowledge-3FarticleName-3D000005906&d=DwICaQ&c=Fge86U5Za1d7PUAcaTHoag0MToOH_fWpqWSEoP8Euxo&r=xdz4rRCzUCiMTlPzdnPEy9-9jLzZpm5SDgO1bwvO1T0&m=qS3KpcI4kSqBPB9p5G3IWLP2u9lzbF5ZeA6cdFqdAJY&s=lEyhu-1AVxnMDNj247L28iKqLLfpSCLyAzAOLhjf8lM&e=

But now, the "Key" column does not exist in the list. Instead, I got a Jason file following the steps in the console. But any values in the fields in the file like "project_id", "private_key_id", "private_key", and "client_id" all didn't work. I get an error "The API Key you have entered cannot be validated with Google".

Answer (score 1):

I could make the key following the steps described in this page.
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#creating_an_api_key

The steps looked almost the same as those in SLD's instruction page.
But somehow, this link below in SDL's instruction page didn't work correctly for me.
https://console.developers.google.com/cloud-resource-manager

I got this error when I tried from the link.
[image: Error Message]